# Routing in Meteor with iron router to different templates

Tags: meteor

I'm still learning the ins and outs of Meteor. I'm using iron router and am routing pages successfully. The layout page where my routes go looks basically like this. They're loading under a header and title with some buttons in it:

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
    ... // some buttons here
    ... // more buttons
  </div>
  <h3>Header Title</h3>
  <div class container>
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I've got the layout template as my default:

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
```

As you can see my routes are loading in the layout template but there's one page I'd like to route to a completely blank template, but right now the it's inside the layout template. Can I have a routes go to different {{> yield}} tags in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Route Controllers:

http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#creating-route-controllers

This will allow you to specify a layoutTemplate on a particular group of routes, rather than globally.  You can then create different groups for different sets of routes requiring different layout templates (and other things, too).